# How to add value to a list with a undefined length?

Tags: python, list, api

I have a list called "new". In it are two values: "name_of_value" & "name_of_value2". They can be accessed by the line

```
new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["name"]=="name_of_value":
new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["name"]=="name_of_value2":
```

I would like to append the values found to a new list found in this. These values can be achieved with this

```
newlist.append(new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["number_value"])
newlist2.append(new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["number_value"])
```

The problem is I'm only getting some of the values to append to the list. I have added a hardcoded "b" but would like to scan through and if there is no value to append none instead. The list has no defined length.

```
b = 0
newlist = []
newlist2 = []
for i in range(len(new)):
    for b in range(20): 
        try:
            if new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["name"]=="name_of_value":
                newlist.append(new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["number_value"])
            if new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["name"]=="name_of_value2":
                newlist2.append(new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["number_value"])
            if b==20:
                newlist.append(None)
                newlist2.append(None)
        except:
            pass
```

The idea is to pull from the custom_fields in this JSON

```
    "custom_fields": [
      {
        "gid": "12345",
        "resource_type": "custom_field",
        "date_value": {
          "date": "2024-08-23",
          "date_time": "2024-08-23T22:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "display_value": "blue",
        "enabled": true,
        "enum_options": [
          {
            "gid": "12345",
            "resource_type": "enum_option",
            "color": "blue",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Low"
          }
        ],
        "enum_value": {
          "gid": "12345",
          "resource_type": "enum_option",
          "color": "blue",
          "enabled": true,
          "name": "Low"
        },
        "multi_enum_values": [
          {
            "gid": "12345",
            "resource_type": "enum_option",
            "color": "blue",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Low"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Status",
        "number_value": 5.2,
        "resource_subtype": "text",
        "text_value": "Some Value",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ],
    "due_on": "2019-09-15",
    "members": [
      {
        "gid": "12345",
        "resource_type": "user",
        "name": "Greg Sanchez"
      }
    ],
    "owner": {
      "gid": "12345",
      "resource_type": "user",
      "name": "Greg Sanchez"
    },
    "permalink_url": "https://app.asana.com/0/resource/123456789/list",
    "public": false,
    "start_on": "2019-09-14",
    "workspace": {
      "gid": "12345",
      "resource_type": "workspace",
      "name": "My Company Workspace"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make a [mcve].  `name 'new' is not defined` is all that code generates.  The way it is being accessed it has sub-dictionaries.  Are you really accessing a structure read from a JSON file?

Comment: The length of the list in each item are different so the challenge is to scan through each item and pick up where this finds a value -  ```newlist.append(new[i]["custom_fields"][b]["number_value"])```

Comment: So show a *working* example by editing the question.

Comment: Sure ive added the sample list provided by Asana. The goal is to get a custom field into a list